# Removing invalid git-subtree-split hash

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm having an issue with a subtree in our repository. I can pull just fine, but when trying to push it chugs along and finally shows me this:

```
fatal: bad object 9775d8fba16f51e14cba873f78129d3d166f5888
```

I did some searching in my `.git` folder and found this:

```
.git/subtree-cache/81555/549ffeaa00e89a145f24ccdb0735c07d8d84b2ff
1:9775d8fba16f51e14cba873f78129d3d166f5888
```

Commit `549ffeaa00e89a145f24ccdb0735c07d8d84b2ff` is an older commit where I did a pull of the subtree. The pull was a squash (as is the preference on the project) and had no issues at the time.

Looking at the commit itself I see this:

```
git-subtree-split: 9775d8fba16f51e14cba873f78129d3d166f5888
```

Which is that bad object causing me issues. This is the only reference to this hash I can find. `git show 9775d8fba16f51e14cba873f78129d3d166f5888` reports bad object and searching the `.git` folder shows only the commit above. So it appears to me that this is the only place where the hash is recorded.

Is there any way to cull this reference out in some way to enable me to push again? I've tried cleaning the repo, re-cloning, deleting the subtree out of my repo and re-pulling it. Nothing seems to remove the reference so I'm guessing there's a deeper issue going on here.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually figured out a way to resolve this error. It might be slightly roundabout but it did the trick:

1. I did a new `git subtree split` with the `--ignore-joins` and `--rejoin` options.
2. I pushed my subtree to a new branch on the remote.
3. I merged the master branch of the remote into my new branch.
4. I merged the new branch back into master.
5. I pulled the subtree back into my app project.

This seems to have resolved the issue by creating a "new" subtree in the app that doesn't contain the commit with the invalid references.

Hopefully if someone else sees the same issue, this might help them out. :)

Comment: `--ignore-joins` did avoid the "bad object" failure when running a `split`, although the extracted history includes merges from the subtreee as well then.

Comment: Adding the remote to the sub-respository and doing a `git remote update` made `git subtree split` work, but at the expense of including merge commits in the history, so new commits need to be cherry-picked from that. I would call that a bug of git subtree as it reference a commit of the sub-repository inside the main repository directly.