# How to fix git subtree rev-parse split issue

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-subtree

I am using SourceTree to interact with branches.
Also, my git knowledge is extremely limited

I have a *NAV-482* branch (/nav.git repository). Subtree branch is *NAV-482-DLL* (/nav.dll.git repository). Subtree name (and local relative path) is *nav.dll*

I have run into issue when I can pull changes from my subtree without any problem, but when I'm trying to push changes into it, I am failing with the followings error:

```
git push using: nav.dll.git NAV-482-DLL
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: could not rev-parse split hash 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd from commit 872b637c702ca5f45b41bdecbded976b47313b23
```

Jumping to the commit 872b637c702ca5f45b41bdecbded976b47313b23 shows that this one is back from 2017 where 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd is git-subtree-split

Not sure why push suddenly choose to die in that way, but now it is a problem.

From what I could find about this issue there are potentially multiple solutions:

[Git push subtree fail unknown revision or path possibly due to missing git-subtree-split commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431546/git-push-subtree-fail-unknown-revision-or-path-possibly-due-to-missing-git-subtr)
suggest using `git fetch <subtree rep> <hash>` to get the commit in question. Unfortunalety it fails:

```
$ git fetch nav.dll.git 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

As I understood this means that this commit is no longer in the repository

[Removing invalid git-subtree-split hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611995/removing-invalid-git-subtree-split-hash) suggest to use `git subtree split --ignore-joins --rejoin` and the persons seems to managed resolve the problem.

This one I am reluctant to try because to be honest, I straight up don't understand what this command will do.
As I understood it should look something like `git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --ignore-joins --rejoin -b NAV-482-TEMP` but what exactly is an expected result? Will it make a separate branch, or will it make a commit into a current checked out NAV-482 branch?

Is the a way to resolve the issue with the SourceTree UI or if there not, how should a proper git subtree split command look, or should I seek for another solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I [illustrated before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334682/6309), make sure to use Git 2.39+ (which includes a bug fix). And consider making a backup of your repository to prevent any accidental loss of data.

Make sure you are on the correct branch (`NAV-482`) in your main repository (`/nav.git`).

```bash
git switch NAV-482
```

Execute the `git subtree split` command to recreate the subtree history.
The command you mentioned should be correct:

```bash
git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --ignore-joins --rejoin -b NAV-482-TEMP
```

- `-P NAV-482-DLL`: specifies the prefix (path) of the subtree.
- `--ignore-joins`: ignores join commits created by previous subtree merges.
- `--rejoin`: creates a new join commit after the split.
- `-b NAV-482-TEMP`: creates a new branch with the split subtree.

That command will create a new branch (`NAV-482-TEMP`) in your main repo with the history of the changes made to the subtree.

Push the newly created branch to the subtree repository.

```bash
git push nav.dll.git NAV-482-TEMP:NAV-482-DLL
```

The `git subtree split` essentially extracts the history of a subfolder (in your case, `nav.dll`) and puts it into a new branch. The `--ignore-joins` and `--rejoin` options help in cleaning and maintaining the correct history.
If some of these operations might not be available or straightforward in the SourceTree UI, particularly the specific options of `git subtree`. You might need to use the command line for these operations.

---

As noted by [Olegs Jasjko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418949/olegs-jasjko) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806718/how-to-fix-git-subtree-rev-parse-split-issue/77816282?noredirect=1#comment137214520_77816282), you can add a squash option:

```
git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --ignore-joins --rejoin --squash -b NAV-482-TEMP
```

With this command, all the changes in the `NAV-482-DLL` subtree will be squashed into a single commit on the new `NAV-482-TEMP` branch. This means the `NAV-482-TEMP` branch will have a simplified history, with one commit representing the entire history of changes from the subtree.

This approach is particularly useful when you want to maintain a cleaner, more concise history in the branch that is being created. It reduces the number of commits and makes it easier to understand the overall changes made in the subtree over time.

---

I suppose a `git reflog show --all | grep 4fb3fa1d8661a6294e798912d39f3ffbbe60a9dd` would return nothing...

If recreating the missing data is not feasible or necessary, you might need to consider methods to bypass this commit in their operations. That could involve adjusting the subtree split to exclude the range involving the missing commit.

Determine the range of commits that are necessary for the subtree split, excluding the missing commit. That involves identifying the commit just before the missing one and the commit just after (or a later commit that is present in the repository).

Generate a series of patches for the commits that you want to include in the subtree. That can be done using `git format-patch`.
Apply these patches to a new branch, effectively recreating the history without the missing commit.

```bash
git switch -c new-branch <commit-before-missing>
git format-patch <commit-before-missing>..<commit-after-missing> --stdout | git apply
```

Alternatively, you can cherry-pick individual commits from the range you identified, again excluding the missing commit. That method is more manual but offers more control over which commits are included.

```bash
git switch -c new-branch <commit-before-missing>
# Cherry-pick commits individually or in a range, excluding the missing one
git cherry-pick <commit-after-missing>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add squash commit to this initial run to make new branch and if yes, will it look something like that:
 git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --ignore-joins --rejoin --squash -b NAV-482-TEMP

or should it be positioned elsewhere?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Sure, you can add a squash commit in the initial run of the `git subtree split` command: it will result in a new branch with a single commit representing the entire history of the subtree, leading to a simplified and more manageable commit history.

Comment: Nope - didn't worked out.
It did create a new branch and so on, however, attempting to push a new branch into subtree gives the same error. In other words, nothing changes except for now in used NAV-482 I have a massive push from source tree (I assume squash didn't worked) and plus a new branch. Absolutely confused

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Do you see one commit on the `NAV-482-TEMP` branch when doing a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`?

Comment: One commit? Do you mean the new subtree split? If that then actually no.
The subtree split was squashed and pushed into NAV-482 and NAV-482-TEMP was actually created in... kinda old state, probably from the last time when data was pulled from subtree. So far I'm just assuming that the initial command for subtree split is incorrect, ether in params order, or something is straight up unnecessary like --rejoin

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Make sure the command is run from the root of the repository and the specified paths and branch names are accurate.
Try running the `git subtree split` command again without the `--rejoin` flag and make sure the path (`-P`) points to the correct subtree directory: `git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --ignore-joins --squash -b NAV-482-TEMP`. After running this command, verify the commit history on the `NAV-482-TEMP` branch: `git log --decorate --oneline --graph NAV-482-TEMP`. You should see a single commit if the squash operation worked correctly.

Comment: --squash command doesn't work without --rejoin. As I understand --rejoin makes a commit in the checked out branch so well, nothing to squash if there are no merge. That being said, running the same command without rejoin and squash, I have no idea what it even did :) It's sure takes a lot of time (~20min). As a result, a new branch was created at the point when there was last time pull from subtree. The subtree split definitely didnt go inside there.

Comment: @OlegsJasjko From [`git subtree` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/git-subtree.1.html), the `--rejoin` flag is not required for `--squash` to function. The `--squash` flag should combine all the changes into a single commit, regardless of whether `--rejoin` is used. Test squash first: `git subtree split -P NAV-482-DLL --squash -b NAV-482-TEMP` and  `git log --decorate --oneline --graph NAV-482-TEMP`

Comment: @OlegsJasjko The process taking a long time (around 20 minutes) can be normal, especially for large repositories or complex histories, if you are using `--rejoin` without the `--ignore-joins` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256633/discussion-between-vonc-and-olegs-jasjko).